# type list doesn't define __round__ method

Tags: python, numpy

Trying to round the output and have tried placing round() in several places and always get the same  error.

```
def stock_change(data):
    # YOUR CODE
    import numpy as n

    m=(len(data)-1)//2
    lower=data[:m+1]
    upper=data[m+1:]
    ml=n.median(round(lower,1))
    mu=n.median(round(upper,1))
    if ml>mu:
      print('average stock value has decreased')
    if ml<mu:
      print('average stock value has increased')
    if ml==mu:
      print('average stock value is unchanged')

print([ml,mu])
```

example of code giving me the error

Answer (score 2):

Round does not accept an iterator. If you're trying to calculate the median of the list and then round that value (as I would expect you are trying to do) you can use:

```
ml=round(n.median(lower))
```

Comment: When i try this I get the error "axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1", maybe this is because I am using google collab?

Comment: Your array must have a different dimension than what the original code was operating on. You can use the updated code, I've removed the axis argument from the median function https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.median.html

Comment: I see, but where do I put the ",1"? It works to give me [4,2], but I am looking to round to give me [4.2,2.0] from a list of [4,3,6,4,1,2,3,2].